# jQuery Flip - flip one div, but show different content based on link clicked

Tags: jquery, jekyll, liquid, flip

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Flip](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) plugin to flip a card around based on the menu item chosen.  Based upon the menu item, the content would be different on the back of the card. Is this possible?

I'm using a jekyll template on github pages.  I'm thinking you could use liquid logic to determine which content to print on the back of the card, but not sure (new to this). Any idea's on how to set this up are much appreciated.

```
<div id="card">
        <div class="front"> <!-- Front of Card -->

           <div id="home" class="col-md-12 main content-panel">

                    <div class="profile-pic">
                        <img src="{{ site.title_image }}" class="img-circle about-image" height="150" width="150" alt="{{ site.title }}" />
                    </div>

                    <h1 class="header author-header" itemprop="headline">{{ site.title }}</h1>

                    <div class="author-text">
                        {{ site.title_description }}
                    </div>
                    {% include nav.html %}

                    {% include social_links.html %}            

                </div> 

              </div> 
              <div class="back"> <!-- Back of Card -->

                <div class="col-md-12 main content-panel">  

           <p>Back of card</p> 
         {% include nav.html %}

      </div>

  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#card").flip({
  axis: 'y',
  trigger: 'click'
});
```

This works to flip card by clicking on card, but instead I would like the nav/menu items to dictate what's on the back of the card. Looking for the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have page1 with content1 and page2 with content2, and you want to show content2 on page2 you can simply use the {{ content }} tag. If you want to show content1 on page2 you will have to loop through the nav items with a for statement.

That is the theory... Now the for the actual code I would set it up using 3 pages: an index file, a content1 file and a content2 file.

Your content1.md (and content2.md) would look like this:

```
----
title: 'Content 1'
intro: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
----
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Your index.html (or navigation.html in _includes) would look like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 

  <div id="card">

     <div class="my-card">
          <div class="front"> 
            <ul class="list-inline">
              {% for page in site.pages %}
              <li><a id="{{ page.title | replace: ' ', '-' }}" href="#">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %} 
          </div> 
          <div id="contentContainer">
            <div class="back">
              {% for page in site.pages %}
              <p id="{{ page.title | replace: ' ', '-' }}">{{ page.intro }} <a href="{{ page.url }}">Read more</a></p>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>

     </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I was able to get the functionality working.  http://goo.gl/K64WfI  Now just figuring out the best way to bring that content into the index.html.  Would I just create a content1.html and a content2.html in the includes folder then bring them in using {% include content1.html %}.

Comment: Is there a way, in liquid, to say "if the content1 link was clicked, show {content1} elseif content2 was clicked..." ?

Comment: Thanks, Joost!  Starting to better understand how liquid works.